# Installing the Angular Material Indigo Pink Theme on Stackblitz?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

Normally we could just add the theme to `styles.css` and it would work.  [For example I have this Stackblitz where it works](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-stepper-demo?file=src%2Fstyles.css);

[However now Stackblitz complains that it can't find the core theme](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-minimal-material-table-demo?file=src/app/app.module.ts).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you misstyped probably copy/pasted from some website. try " or ' instead of “

Answer (score 1):

Problem is there is typo in the quotes that you use there in your string it should be

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

instead you are using

```
@import “~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css”;
```

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-minimal-material-table-demo-z5tzsr)

Comment: Crap - YES - I keep forgetting this when copying from medium - THANK YOU!